# How to organize files in resources folder

Tags: java, maven, junit, project-structure

I am working on bigger project and I would like to ask how should I organize files used for unit tests in resources folder. I used to put it directly in resources folder, but how the project grows, it is getting messy. Is there some convention for this? Should I for example for class `com.znamenacek.somepackage.MyClass.java` put it in `resources/com/znamenacek/somepackage/Myclass` ?

Comment: I hope you put them into `src/test/resources` directory. If those resources related to particular classes I would add the package (directory) into the resources directory as well.. if there are too much you might need to separate your module into two modules...

Comment: Hi khmarbaise, thank you for you answer. Yes, I am putting them under `src/test/resources`. I just wasn't sure how to organise them there. From you reply I understand that if the file is necessary for the test testing concrete class, it should be in the directory structure similar to package. So for `com.znamenacek.somepackage.MyClass.java` it should be in `src/test/resources/com/znamenacek/somepackage/Myclass` right?

Comment: Yes I would go that direction. The other question is why do you need so many resources? Usually unit tests tend not that often to really need resources..(only my POV)..